# Tikz : size of the printed image is smaller than it is suppose to be

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle ++ (5cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

It is suppose to be a square with side of 5cm but, when I print it, I have a square with side of 4.8cm.

Does anyone knows what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Could it be a problem with printing margins or scaling?

Comment: Add `\pdfcompresslevel=0` at the beginning of your `.tex`. And then open the PDF in any text editor. You will see a lot of `141.7341`. These are dimensions in postscript point and they are `5.00006408 cm`. So it is probably your printer to blame.

Comment: Also beware "scale and fit" print options.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*German Printing Dialoge in Adobe Reader*

[image]

> Make sure that you choose the correct scaling option in the print
>   options*. Sometimes the default option scales the document.

*Also mentioned in the comment from user *John Kormylo*.